# parse Json with key "params" in mvc4

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I am receiving a json-string though a HTTP-POST from an external service (which is out of my control). One of the keys in this json is `params:{...},`

i need to map this json to a class `MyClass`. This would be simple, were it not for the fact that `params` is a keyword in C#..

I've tried using Newtonsofts json.NET(version 7.0.0) library, and have the following in `MyClass`:

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "params")]
    public TrustlyNotifParams Parameters { get; set;}
```

but `Parameters` ends up as `null`. The posted json has a nested value for params, I've seen this through logging.

everything above `Parameters` in the hierarchy gets parsed just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You could use the keyword, you just have to use it like `public TrustlyNotifParams @params { get; set; }`, otherwise would you mind posting a full example of the JSON so we can see what the problem may be?

Comment: awesome I had no idea you could do that! Make it an answer and I shall accept it! =) also upvotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (sparingly please) make keywords as the names of properties or variables, you just need to tell the compiler to treat it as such. This is the same way you tell it to treat a string as literal instead of using escape sequences:

```
public TrustlyNotifParams @params { get; set; }
```

The `@` symbol tells the compiler to treat the following as a variable, field, property name, etc.